# python - socket.gethostbyname() outputting wrong IP Address

Tags: python, sockets, ip, gethostbyname

socket.gethostbyname('mypcname.local') is giving an IP of 172.23.260.1 which is the IP for WSL on my laptop. However, im expecting to get my wifi ip address in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

Is there a way to get the correct IP without disabiling the WSL network adaptor? Why is it defaulting to the 172.23.260.0(WSL) subnet instead of my home network subnet?

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150

Comment: is this inside or outside WSL?